# Out of scope before return

Tags: c++

The following code snippet is a simplified version of a problem I'm having in visual studio.

The code is entering the destructor during

```
return temp;
```

debug single stepping.

Code:

```
class point2d
{
   public:
    int x, y;
};
class poly2d
{
   public:

    void operator=(const poly2d& temp)
    {
        for (cnt = 0; cnt < pointNum; ++ cnt)
        {
            p[cnt].x = temp.x;
            p[cnt].y = temp.y;
        }
    }


    poly2d(int size);
    ~poly2d();

   point2d* p;
   int pointNum;
};

poly2d::poly2d(int size)
{
    pointNum = size;
    p = new point2d[size];
}

poly2d::~poly2d()
{
    if (p)
    {
        delete[] p;
        p = 0;
    }
}

poly2d copy();

int main()
{
    poly2d myPoly(5);

    myPoly = copy();

    return 1;
}

poly2d copy()
{
    poly2d temp(5);

    return temp;
}
```

I'm aware this piece makes no sense but it's simplified and out of context but at the same time highlights my issue.  The destructor is being executed before the return statement.  Followed by the copy constructor, then destructor again.  It's being deleted twice and causing errors obviously.  This is the first time I've had this issue in 6+ years of tinkering.

Thanks.

Comment: It's because you don't have a correct copy constructor or assignment operator. Others will explain the specifics.. If you used `std::vector<point2d>` then everything would just work. You wouldn't even need to provide a destructor. Let the language do the hard work for you.

Comment: What destructor do you mean? The local object `temp` is of course destroyed, once it goes out of scope.

Comment: You're returning by value. You even named the object `temp`. Why do you think it should not be destructed? Your errors have nothing to do with "going out of scope" — they are due to you violating the Rule of Zero/Three/Five.

Comment: I've added a an assignment operator for = and it's not executing till after the destructor.

Comment: Yes, temp should go out of scope, that's not the issue.  The issue is copying this variable to myPoly before that.

Comment: Compilers can make some hidden temporary variables when returning from functions. In general, I wouldn't try to understand how bad code works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement the Rule of Three/Five, but I would recommend going for the [Rule of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/). It's based on the following principle:

> Classes that have custom destructors, copy/move constructors or
> copy/move assignment operators should deal exclusively with ownership.
> Other classes should not have custom destructors, copy/move
> constructors or copy/move assignment operators.

You can simplify your code to the following:

```
struct point2d
{
    int x, y;
};

struct poly2d
{
    poly2d(std::vector<point2d>::size_type size);

    std::vector<point2d> p;
};
```

The vector will handle copying and memory management automagically, no extra work needs to be expended. An example constructor would look something like the following:

```
poly2d(std::vector<point2d>::size_type size)
  : p(size)
{
}
```

Comment: You may want to provide an example constructor implementation to help him.

Comment: Why do you use different parameter types in your example, and use reserve instead of resize? Don't make it more confusing than it has to be.

Comment: @NeilKirk I can't guess the OP's intentions. It is an *example* after all.

Comment: He is allocating an array of a particular size. If you are going to suggest vector, at least provide an example which logically does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You did not define a copy assignment constructor for your class poly2d. In that case your compiler will generate a default constructor for you. All this constructor does is copy every field of your class.

That means in particular, that copies the pointer point2d* p, not the underlying point.

So what happens when you call copy()?

You generate a new poly2d, i.e. the poly2d constructor is called. That generates a new point2d. Now your call to copy() is finished. What is actually assigned to your poly2d myPoly is a copy of your temp object. The destructor of the temp object gets called as soon as the function call to copy() is finished. This destructor destroys the point2d object that the temp object pointed to. The trouble now is, that at no point in time a new point2d object for myPoly was created. myPoly has a pointer to the object that temp was pointing to, which now is drestroyed. That is of course bad.

You can fix that by defining your own copy/ copy assignment constructors and making sure that a new point2d gets created everytime you copy a poly2d. Or, as already suggested, you can use a std::vector instead.

Comment: Ah yes.  I was getting mixed up between assignment operator and copy constuctor...I thought the void operator= WAS the copy constructor, whereas this too just calls the copy constructor.  I'm not a pro programmer so for hobbyist stuff I'd rather not use vectors in real time graphics routines as they are quite expensive.  Correct, oh yes, but expensive.

Comment: This also explains why I'm getting 2 executions of same destructor.  The shallow copy copied the pointer variable as is.  Dangly.  Thanks all for your responses.